# Customised HTML and dropdowns - jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I want to extend the styling and some of the functionality of the jQuery UI Datepicker but am having trouble modifying the html that gets generated.

Specifically, I'm trying to have a centralised Year and month set of drop downs that sit at the top of a double-calendar view. I'd like the default 'Next' and 'Back' arrows to be placed on either side of the centralised drop down.

This is an image of what i'm trying to achieve:
[image: Centralised drop down selection with arrows]

The reason I need to do this is that my 2 month-view calendar has month titles over each datepicker calendar:

[image: full calendar showing calendar months with month names]

I'd like to be able to move the arrows to either side of a central month/year dropdown that I can't figure out how to create. From what I understand I think I need to extend the jquery Ui Datepicker plugin but I don't know where to begin to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far styling of a calendar is concerned, you will have to overwrite jquery.ui.css for specific css classes and write your own CSS with same class names.

For Month and Year buttons, you can create your own control for this and enable jQuery datepicker on the click of these controls. Ideally jQuery Datepicker is just a control which can be enabled from a textbox or button. So it doesn't matter how your source look like. All you need to do is enable datepicker from your custom control/button.